# New install doMPI throwing MPI_ERR_SPAWN error

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mpi

I updated `open-mpi` to 3.0.0, reloaded `Rmpi` and `doMPI`, and now getting this error when executing `startCluster` on Ubuntu Linux, R 3.4.2.

```
Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = rscript, slavearg = args, nslaves = count,  : 
  MPI_ERR_SPAWN: could not spawn processes
```

How to diagnose problem?

Comment: Start with simple MPI code. Make sure you can compile and run simple MPI Hello World app. Maybe your OpenMPI installation is "broken".

Comment: Thanks mko.  This is all new to me but   this works 

`mpirun -np 6 mpi_hello_world
Hello world from processor JAM-Home-PC, rank 1 out of 6 processors
Hello world from processor JAM-Home-PC, rank 5 out of 6 processors
Hello world from processor JAM-Home-PC, rank 2 out of 6 processors
... but this does not

jamaas:code$ mpirun -np 7 mpi_hello_world
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 7 slots ...:
  mpi_hello_world

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots available for use.`

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704637/mpirun-not-enough-slots-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test your MPI installation, do following:

```
/* Put this text inside hello.c file */
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank;
    int world;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world);
    printf("Hello: rank %d, world: %d\n",rank, world);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Then, compile it

```
mpicc -o hello ./hello.c
```

and then, try to run it

```
mpirun -np 2 ./hello
```

If you get

```
Hello: rank 0, world: 2
Hello: rank 1, world: 2
```

It means your MPI installation is fine and you have to look inside R, otherwise it means that MPI is not correctly configured and there are low chances to get any further.

**Update**

It looks like R3.4 + OpenMPI 3.0.0 + Rmpi missbehave ;)

If you try run slaves outside R, it works. So, I guess there is some issue inside native code of Rmpi.

```
> cp -r /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rmpi ~
> cd ~/Rmpi
> mpirun -np 2 ./Rslaves.sh `pwd`/slavedaemon.R tmp needlog /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/
# if you put 
# localhost slots=25
# inside ~/.hostfile, you can acquire more resources
> mpirun --hostfile=~/.hostfile -np 4 ./Rslaves.sh `pwd`/slavedaemon.R tmp needlog /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/
```

**Update with proper fix for R 3.4 and OpenMPI 3.0.0**

Create file: `~/.openmpi/mca-params.conf` and put inside

```
orte_default_hostfile=YOUR_USER_HOME/default_host
```

Create file: `~/default_host` with content

```
localhost slots=25
```

Run R, load RMpi and run code

```
> library(Rmpi)
> mpi.spawn.Rslaves()
    4 slaves are spawned successfully. 0 failed.
master (rank 0, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: pi
slave1 (rank 1, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: pi
slave2 (rank 2, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: pi
slave3 (rank 3, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: pi
slave4 (rank 4, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: pi
```

For full story, take a look here: [R3.4 + OpenMPI 3.0.0 + Rmpi inside macOS - little bit of mess ;)](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3792)